# how to convert an unsigned value to struct tm?

Tags: c++

I am getting absolute time value like as follows,

```
1413399540000
1411047780000
1411574340000
```

How can I convert them to "struct tm" in c++?

Hi Joachim,

this is an input from GUI for accesslist time range and    i tried the following,

typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

```
uint64_t mytime;
struct tm *tm;
time_t realtime;

mytime = 1447862580005ULL;
realtime = (time_t) (mytime / 1000000);
printf ("The current local time is: %s", ctime(&realtime));
tm = localtime(&realtime);
printf ("The current local time is: %s", asctime(tm));

tm->tm_year +=1900;
tm->tm_mon +=1;

printf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
        tm->tm_year,tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday,
        tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
```

o/p :

```
The current local time is: Sat Jan 17 10:11:02 1970
The current local time is: Sat Jan 17 10:11:02 1970
1970-01-17 10:11:02
```

Looks confuse to me.Not sure how to verify the conversion got corect value or not.

Comment: What unit is those time-stamps in? And what have you tried?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/

Comment: Hi Joachim, this is an input from GUI for accesslist time range and    i tried the following,

Comment: When adding code, please *edit* your question. And are the times in seconds? Milliseconds? Some other unit?

Comment: Are you sure the times are *micro* seconds and not *milli* seconds?

Comment: Will ask to GUI team which unit they are sending. Will update you the same.

Answer (score 4):

`1413399540000` looks like a number of milliseconds since unix epoch, namely `15.10.2014 18:59:00`.

```
auto millisec = 1413399540000;
time_t time = millisec / 1000;

tm local;
localtime_r(&time, &local); // TODO: Check the errors.

tm utc;
gmtime_r(&time, &utc); // TODO: Check the errors.
```

Comment: I would mention localtime_r() for clarity

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin in which header is `gmtime_r` defined?

Comment: @BrunoBieri In `<time.h>`. It is a [Posix function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thank you!